# Map jdbc record set to Record Type with nested types in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

Soooooo I want to use a nested record and have it loaded from a sql/jdbc recordSet in Ballerina.

If we have:

```
type Foo record{
  string bar;
  string baz;
}
```

we can directly create Foo records from a resultSet with matching form:

```
table<Foo>|error dt = testDB->select("SELECT bar,baz FROM ferble",Foo);
```

but is there a way to do....

```
type Foo record{
  string bar;
  Baz baz;
}

type Baz record{
  string qux;
  string quxx;
}

table<Foo>|error dt = testDB->select("SELECT bar,qux,quxx FROM ferble",Foo);
```

While it's easy to do in code, when the results are wide it gets very tedious. If you're trying to create a record which can be converted to schema defined JSON, it'd be nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Foo record {
  string bar;
  Baz baz;
}

type Baz record {
  string qux;
  string quxx;
}

table<Foo>|error dt = testDB->select("SELECT bar,qux,quxx FROM ferble",Foo);
```

This is not allowed in Ballerina. Also, it would be semantically incorrect to allow it because, the record type represents the table schema where each column type is mapped to the Ballerina record field type. This query returns a result set which has 3 columns with a type associated each column. Then the Ballerina record you try to map a given row to, should have the corresponding types as field types.

But if you were selecting as below,

```
table<Foo>|error dt = testDB->select("SELECT bar,baz FROM ferble",Foo);
```

where, baz is a user-defined type/struct type in the database with qux and quxx fields, then mapping that to the aforementioned Foo record would be correct.

Comment: The reason I ask is that works in some other frameworks. Since the compiler/runtime knows that Baz is a non-standard/complex type (and hence cannot be mapped directly to the returned SQL type), mapping the two next columns to the fields of the complex type is possible. The query returns three values, which, via this methodology, be mapped to the three "primitive" values contained by the hierarchy, in appropriate order, as Ballerina maps by index, not key.

Comment: Still I feel like it is not the right thing to do. Anyway, please create an issue at https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues so that Ballerina team can evaluate the possibility of doing this.